# Python error No such file or directory but the file is there

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a python script. The first steps of the scripts run ok, but at some point I have this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chodar/Descargas/00.Comprimidos/REPET_linux-x64-2.2/bin/LaunchTRF.py", line 154, in <module>
    iLaunchTRF.run()        
  File "/home/chodar/Descargas/00.Comprimidos/REPET_linux-x64-2.2/bin/LaunchTRF.py", line 143, in run
    self._launchTRF()
  File "/home/chodar/Descargas/00.Comprimidos/REPET_linux-x64-2.2/bin/LaunchTRF.py", line 101, in _launchTRF
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2015-08-28 12:38:05 - DetectTEFeatures - ERROR - ERROR when launching 'LaunchTRF.py -i TEs.60bp.fa -o TEs.60bp.fa.SSR.set -m 15 -c -v 0 > launchTRF.log'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PASTEClassifier.py", line 199, in <module>
    iLaunch.run()        
  File "PASTEClassifier.py", line 165, in run
    iDF.run()
  File "/home/chodar/Descargas/00.Comprimidos/REPET_linux-x64-2.2/commons/tools/DetectTEFeatures.py", line 185, in run
    self._detectFeatures()
  File "/home/chodar/Descargas/00.Comprimidos/REPET_linux-x64-2.2/commons/tools/DetectTEFeatures.py", line 204, in _detectFeatures
    self._detectTRF()
  File "/home/chodar/Descargas/00.Comprimidos/REPET_linux-x64-2.2/commons/tools/DetectTEFeatures.py", line 267, in _detectTRF
    self._logAndRaise("ERROR when launching '%s'" % cmd)
  File "/home/chodar/Descargas/00.Comprimidos/REPET_linux-x64-2.2/commons/tools/DetectTEFeatures.py", line 176, in _logAndRaise
    raise Exception(errorMsg)
Exception: ERROR when launching 'LaunchTRF.py -i TEs.60bp.fa -o TEs.60bp.fa.SSR.set -m 15 -c -v 0 > launchTRF.log'
```

I read some other posts with this type of error and based on them, I looked if the LaunchTRF.py existed and it is there. In fact, when I run only LaunchTRF.py without any option, I can see the list of options and the help. I was thinking that the missing file is TEs.60bp.fa, but it is also there.

Here are the lines 98 to 103 from LaunchTRF.py in case that may help:

```
 def _launchTRF(self):
        cmd = "trf %s 2 3 5 80 10 20 %d -h -d" % (self.inFileName, self.maxPeriod)
        self._log.debug("Running : %s" % cmd)
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = process.communicate()
        self._log.debug("Output:\n%s" % output[0])
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: can you do a print(self.inFileName). Make sure that file has the full path name not just blah.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
print(self.inFileName)
```

should be equal to

```
"C:\blah\something\test.txt"
```

if it isn't just prepend the name in your command

```
fullFile = "C:\blah\hooray\"+self.inFileName

cmd = "trf %s 2 3 5 80 10 20 %d -h -d" % (fullFile, self.maxPeriod)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a issue with your working directory, maybe the parent script is changing it, or you are executing the parent script from another directory.

What you could do to fix that is to change de working directory by passing an additional parameter to popen:

`subprocess.Popen('./LaunchTRF.py ...', cwd='/path/to/')`

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Filipe I will try this solution and i let you know

Comment: I modify the subprocess.Popen to process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,cwd="/home/chodar/Descargas/00.Comprimidos/REPET_linux-x64-2.2/bin/"). Did not work, but im not if I do it fine...

Comment: Hi Filipe. Im out off office without change to establish an ssh connection. I will try soon as possible and let you know. Thanks alot.

Comment: Probably it's missing a ./ before LaunchTRF.py. This is because setting the working directory with cwd doesn't affect the search path. So I think if you just do:

`subprocess.Popen('./LaunchTRF.py ...', cwd='/path/to/')`

it should work